# Nonsense in SWI Prolog trace

Tags: trace, swi-prolog

I am using SWI Prolog 6.6.4 on Windows 7. When I run programs with trace, all I seem to get is a load of jumbled Chinese/Arabic characters. Example output includes lines like:

```
Call: (6) ...锠销锿销锠销
ꀊꀀ   Call: (7) ...꜠꜀ꜿ꜀꜠꜀ꀀꁥꀀꁥꀀꁰꀀ
ꀊꀀ   Exit: (7) ...뀠뀀뀿뀀뀠뀀ꁣꀀꁲꀀꁥꀀꁥꀀꁰꀀ
```

Does anyone know what to do to eliminate these characters so that the trace runs as normal?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found this discussion:
http://swi-prolog.996271.n3.nabble.com/Weird-characters-displayed-when-trace-is-on-td14628.html
It seems to be a bug in the current version which will be solved in the next (actually, it is already solved in the beta-versions).